# Apache and PHP interaction

Tags: apache-2.2, php

Suppose we have a typical LAMP setup. When a person requests a web page coded in php, what happens at the Apache level? Does Apache create a new php instance to create and return that web page? Or is there a continuous php instance running at all times?

Basically, here is how I think it works:

- Person visits http://example.com/index.php
- Apache receives the request, spins up an instance of php to create the page
- Page is created, sent back to the requesting browser
- PHP instance is closed

Thus, only one php instance deals with page requests...Is my thinking correct on this?

Comment: Depends. mpm-prefork uses "workers" that execute the PHP and pass the result back, while mpm-worker uses Apache's internal workers and mod_php to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you are utilizing PHP. If you're not utilizing CGI/FastCGI (which would make your statement correct) then PHP is actually run in a module (see /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf, or httpd.conf for the include php module). Which means that when Apache has a kid, each process already has a binary of PHP. So, Apache runs the interpreter against a set of hooks and the page is rendered.

CGI is the method which is executed as a single process.